# iScroll sticks after "next" or after focus on input box

Tags: ios, iphone-web-app

Running iScroll in a basic web app for iOS, and I have noticed that if I press "Next" on the keypad, iScroll will not scroll above the highlighted input box, even if I move off of it. Any tips?

Comment: This question is going to be hard for anyone to answer. I didn't know what iScroll is, how have you implemented it, what do you think the problem is?